# Executing two asynctask in in two different classes

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have 2 AsyncTasks in two different classes but the problem is when the first is do in backgroung state the second is not executed. The first asyncTask if preformed in loop because it needs to update every 5 seconds the new data. If i stop the task (condition = flase) the second one works perfectly.

First class:

```
public class MapScreen extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_screen);

        UpdateUserCords updateUC = new UpdateUserCords();
        updateUC.execute();
    }

class UpdateUserCords extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
{


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


        while(condition)
        {

            //some code in loop...


            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {


        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {


        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}

}
```

Second class:

```
public class Groups extends Activity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_groups);


    getGroups getGr = new getGroups();
    getGr.execute(); //not executing, no error or crash


}


class getGroups extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
{


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //some code...
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }


}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After Android API 11, `AsyncTask`s started to run on serial executor by default, that means that only one task is running at a time. To get the behavior of prior to API 11, which is running on `ThreadPoolExecutor`, you'll need to specify it in the code like this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
  myTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
}
else {
  myTask.execute();
}
```

Please take a look here for more information:
http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/04/20/asynctask-threading-regression-confirmed.html

Good luck!

P.S. It's not recommended to use `AsyncTask` for an infinite thread, `AsyncTask` purpose is to do a Task on the background, not to run forever, so if you want an infinite thread, I think you should create it as a `Thread` and not as an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Thank you, but I assume that serial executor is better than ThreadPoolExecutor if it is in newer API version. It may cause problems with the code or slow execution?

Comment: It's not in terms of some executor is better than the other, they have different roles. Serial executor means that only one task will be running in the same time (this is the default, from what I remember, they chose it as default because many people didn't get along with multi threading). ThreadPool executor means that many tasks can run in the same time, and this is the behavior you wish to achieve, so this is the executor you need to use to achieve it, very simple.

Comment: @user1891408, you are welcomed! I edited the answer and explained something in P.S, please read it.

Answer (score 0):

You asynctasks are in two different activities. 
Only one activity is active at any time.

Comment: I know my asynctasks are in two different activities, but when i start the second activity I can see that the first asyncTask is still working. This is not the answer, it just another way to look at the problem.

Comment: Well you should call the asynctask cancel( boolean ) method on your activity's onPause method if you want to stop the asynctask when leaving the activity. You can also execute the asynctask on the onResume method, so when the user comes back from another activity, the asynctask runs

Answer (score -1):

Both classes extend Activity and only one of them is running at the same time.
If you want a task to be execute longer than the lifetime of an activity, you have to wrap it into an [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Comment: Actualy I dont wish that my AsyncTask run longer than my activity, but when I open second activity the first is not finished. I don`t wish to finish it because I wont that the user could back to first activity by pressing back button

Comment: Once the user navigates to another activity, it's no longer under you control if your activity gets destroyed or not. Check out http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html If you don't stop your Asycn Task, it could lead to a leaked Thread. So why a downvote for this?

Comment: That's wrong, first of all, if one activity is running it doesn't mean that the other is already finished, one Activity can run and the other will be paused. But even if he start an AsyncTask in Activity A, and then starts Activity B, and as you said the, Activity A getting killed, the AsyncTask keep on running, so this is not the problem he is describing.

Comment: Yeah, and that's the problem. The AsyncTask could keep running infinite and you dont have a reference to it, therefore you could never stop it. So a Service would be the proper way to execute long running tasks. ;)

Comment: @JohannesStaehlin, you are more than right, but that's not the solution for his problem :)

Comment: That's why I shared the link to Services. He should rather redesign of his application instead of using hacks and workarounds.

Comment: @JohannesStaehlin, I don't think that you can assume that he should use `Service` because both me and you don't see the `AsyncTask`'s code and can't know its purpose. `Service` is not always a good alternative to `AsyncTask` and doesn't always fit.