# Executing two AsyncTask parallely

Tags: java, android, crash, android-asynctask, helper

i want to execute two AsyncTask in parallely. Basically I wanted to do when I click on a button you run the two AsyncTask but at the same time are not so ... On the first part click the first to second the second in the order! I would understand if it is possible go start them with the click of a button!

I write below the code that I utilzizato to let her go:

```
public void onClick(View arg0){
    switch(arg0.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_down:
            if(isOnline() == true){
                //
                // new ShowDialogAsyncTask().execute();
                new AsynTask2().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,null);
                new ShowDialogAsyncTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR,null);



            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(this,"Connettiti a Internet",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: refer this Link very importing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14223998/executing-two-asynctask-in-in-two-different-classes?rq=1

Comment: Could you please rephrase, I have a hard time understanding you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068984/running-multiple-asynctasks-at-the-same-time-not-possible) is very useful discussion regarding how to run multiple AsyncTask() parallely.

Moreover,it also have one [example](https://github.com/vitkhudenko/test_asynctask) which demonstrate the same.

Hope this helps .... :)

Answer (score 0):

onPostExecute of the first asynctask you could start the second

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     new AsynTask2().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,null);
 }
```

Comment: Thats actually how you could do it, but the .executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,null) is not necessary.

Comment: wait not sure what the question intends, does he needs parllel or sequential. i did not quite understand

Comment: @blganesh101 In the way you wrote yourself ... the second AsyncTask is executed at the end of 1 AsyncTask right? I want them to do in parallel: that is, when the 1st part also the 2nd

Comment: This allows for parallel execution on all android versions with API 4+ (Android 1.6+):

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) // API 11
void startMyTask(AsyncTask asyncTask) {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params);
    else
        asyncTask.execute(params);
}

Comment: what is params? i do this:   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {

                        new ShowDialogAsyncTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, null);
                        new AsynTask2().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,null);
                    }
                    else {
                        new AsynTask2().execute();
                        new ShowDialogAsyncTask().execute();
                    }

Comment: params refer to the parameters you will be sending to asynctasks. if nothing use null

Comment: is right so? if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) { new ShowDialogAsyncTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, null); new AsynTask2().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,null); } else { new AsynTask2().execute(); new ShowDialogAsyncTask().execute(); }

Comment: what is this error: 06-25 12:28:38.654  18733-19092/com.example.megacodownloader   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
        java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
        at